# Loading a Composer package not listed in vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php, fine-uploader

I have an application written in CakePHP 3. I've installed Cake and other packages via Composer.

The most recent one I installed was `fineuploader/php-traditional-server` (https://packagist.org/packages/fineuploader/php-traditional-server) by 
placing this in my `composer.json` then running `composer update`:

```
 "require": {
    "fineuploader/php-traditional-server": "1.1.0"
 }
```

This has downloaded the files as expected into `vendor/fineuploader/php-traditional-server`.

However, if I try to reference that in one of my Cake Controllers, like this:

```
use UploadHandler;

public function test()
{
    var_dump(new \UploadHandler);
}
```

It errors saying  **Class 'UploadHandler' not found**

The only way I've been able to get the above to run is by hard-coding a link to the appropriate file. So instead of `use UploadHandler;` I have

```
require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor/fineuploader/php-traditional-server/handler.php');
```

I read on https://jtreminio.com/2012/10/composer-namespaces-in-5-minutes/ that `vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php` is supposed to contain the namespaces that can be autoloaded. But when I open that file up, there's no reference to this package (in fact there are only about 3 whereas my `vendor` directory has loads of packages some of which I can use just fine).

So what is the correct way to load `UploadHandler`? I thought the point of using Composer was that it took care of autoloading these files, so you *didn't* have to use things like `require()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read the note in the `handler.php` file?

> Do not use or reference this directly from your client-side code. Instead, this should be required via the endpoint.php or endpoint-cors.php file(s)

So AFAICT the package doesn't define any autoloading capabilites because you're not supposed to use the `UploadHandler` class directly, but instead you should require the `endpoint.php` or `endpoint-cors.php` file, which do not include any classes, and should only be required when needed.

Surely these endpoint files are not compatible with CakePHP, so you may have a reason to use the handler class directly. The package however doesn't use namespaces, and the classname doesn't match the filename, ie it follows neither PSR-0 nor PSR-4 conventions, and as already mentioned, the packages `composer.json` doesn't define any autoloading configuration, so no matter what conventions the package would follow, this would result in no autoloading capabilities for the packages PHP classes/files.

So if you want autoloading capability, you could fix this on your end by for example adding a `classmap` autoload entry to your projects `composer.json`, like:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "vendor/fineuploader/php-traditional-server/"
        ]
    }
}
```

Then re-dump the autoloader, and autoloading should work fine:

```
$ composer dump-autoload
```

See also

- **[Composer Docs > The composer.json Schema > autoload > Classmap](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap)**
- **[Composer Docs > Command-line interface / Commands > dump-autoload](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload)**